# Decompor numero imenso em javascript

Tags: javascript

Continuando com esta [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25174/como-decompor-um-n%C3%BAmero-em-pot%C3%AAncias-de-2)

O problema e com quantidade de numeros existente na minha variavel, ou seja, nao estou conseguindo pegar os valores acima de `1073741824` e queria chegar no `562949953421312` de acordo com a minha questao passada.

Existem algum limite de numeros na variavel em javascript?

No meu `console.log(fatores)`, mostra um array vazio, ou negativo(depende do numero).

```
n = 562949953421312;
power = 0;
var fatores = []
while (n != 0) {
    if ((n & 1) != 0) {
        fatores[fatores.length] = (1 << power);
    }
    ++power;
    n >>>= 1;
}
console.log(fatores) // returna vazio `[]`
```

Comment: TL;DR: JavaScript representa números como ponto flutuante de 64 bits, mas as operações bit-a-bit tratam eles como se fossem inteiros de 32 bits. Veja minha resposta abaixo pra mais detalhes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Números em JavaScript são `double`s, ou seja, [ponto flutuante](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_flutuante) com precisão "dupla" (64 bits). Isso significa que o maior número inteiro representável com precisão é `2^53 = 9007199254740992` (números maiores podem ser representados, mas com "buracos" entre um e outro).

Se você precisa representar números maiores que `2^53`, então sugiro procurar uma biblioteca de "big number" (ou "big integer", ou "big decimal"). Não conheço nenhuma em particular para recomendar, mas existem várias, basta ver exatamente o que você precisa e se a biblioteca dá suporte (em geral, pelo menos as operações aritméticas básicas serão suportadas).

Essas bibliotecas normalmente fazem isso usando não uma variável, mas um array de números para representar um número maior. Ou seja, a precisão suportada é virtualmente ilimitada, exceto é claro pela quantidade de memória no seu computador (ou pelo número máximo de elementos num array suportado pela linguagem/implementação). Naturalmente, o desempenho das mesmas é inferior ao uso de uma única variável, portanto essas bibliotecas somente devem ser usadas quando realmente necessário.

**Atualização:** Embora JavaScript representa números como `double`s, as operações bit-a-bit (*bitwise*) como `<<`, `>>>`, `&`, etc [tratam seus operandos como se fossem inteiros de 32 bits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). Por essa razão, o maior número que pode ser tratado por esses operadores não é `2^53`, mas `2^31-1 = 2147483647` (o maior inteiro positivo representável em 32 bits). Tentar utilizá-los com números maiores vai causar então um comportamento inesperado.

Modifiquei o código para usar multiplicação/divisão simples por `2` - em vez de operações *bitwise*, e ele agora funciona como esperado:

```
    var n = 562949953421312;
    var power = 1;
    var fatores = [];
    while (n != 0) {
        if (n % 2 !== 0) {
            fatores[fatores.length] = power;
            n--;
        }
        power *= 2;
        n /= 2;
    }
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RY9rc/6/) (escreva um número na caixa de texto e pressione <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: veja meu post editado,

Comment: @fsi Estou testando o código no jsFiddle. De fato, [o código original](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/RY9rc/) apresenta problemas com números grandes - talvez pelo uso do *shift left*? [Alterei o código](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/RY9rc/1/) para usar aritmética simples, sem o shift, e melhorou um pouco... Só não consigo entender por que ainda está dando problema com alguns números (funcionou com `562949953421311`, mas não com `562949953421312`...)